# Control de bloques if else

Tags: c, algoritmos, if

El programa ejecuta sin problemas, pero siempre escribe la última sentencia `printf("lo siento, no puedo calcularlo");`

**¿Hay alguna forma de que no salga por esta condición?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main () {
    float i, v, r, a, b=0, c=0;

    printf("calculadora ley de ohm \t\t(Si no tienes un valor pon 0)");
    printf("\n\nIntensidad:\t 0\nVoltaje:\t 0\nResistencia:\t 0\n\n");

    printf("Intensidad? \n");
    scanf("%f", &i);

    printf("Voltaje? \n");
    scanf("%f", &v);

    printf("resistencia? \n");
    scanf("%f", &r);

    printf("\n\nIntensidad:\t %.2f\nVoltaje:\t %.2f\nResistencia:\t %.2f\n", i, v, r);

    a=v/r;
    if (i==0){  
        printf("intensidad: %.2f", a);
        b=i*r;
    }
    else{ 
        if (v==0){ 
            printf("Voltaje: %.2f", b);
            c=v/i;
        }else{ 
            if (r==0){ 
                printf("resistencia: %.2f", c);
            }
            else {
                printf("lo siento, no puedo calcularlo");
            }
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: en que caso no quieres que se muestre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema en la lógica de tu programa. Para empezar estas anidando los condicionales, cuando no debe ser así. A no ser que no comprenda lo que intentas hacer, la idea es implemtar una estructura `if`-`else if`-`else`, que seria algo así

> ```
> if (expresión)
>   {
>     Bloque de código;
>   }
> else if(expresión)
>   {
>     Bloque de código;
>   }
> else
>   {
>     Bloque de código;
>   }
> ```

Aun eliminando la anidación la lógica no es correcta:

- Si `I` es 0 se ejecuta el código del if independientemente del valor de `A` y `V`.
- Si `I` no es cero pero `v` es 0, se ejecuta lo que hay dentro del primer `else if` independientemente del valor de `R`.
- Si `I` e `V` son cero pero `R` no lo es, se ejecuta el código del segundo `else if`.
- El `else` solo se ejecuta **si todas las variables son distintas de 0**.

Esto no es lo que deseas, en síntesis necesitas comprobar cual de las tres variables es cero (la que quieres calcular), si hay mas de una que son desconocidas (o la resistencia es negativa) no se puede calcular nada. Esto nos deja tres posibilidades válidas:

- i = 0 y a ≠ 0 y r > 0
- r = 0 y i ≠ 0 y r ≠ 0
- a = 0 y i ≠ 0 y r > 0

> **Nota**: la intensidad y el voltaje pueden ser negativos, pero no la resistencia.

Necesita hacer estas tres comprobaciones en tu construcción `if- else if`. De forma que se ejecute el `else` si ninguna se cumple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float i = 0, v = 0, r = 0;

    printf("calculadora ley de ohm \t\t(Si no tienes un valor pon 0)");
    printf("\n\nIntensidad:\t 0\nVoltaje:\t 0\nResistencia:\t 0\n\n");

    printf("Intensidad? \n");
    scanf("%f", &i);

    printf("Voltaje? \n");
    scanf("%f", &v);

    printf("Resistencia? \n");
    scanf("%f", &r);


    if (i==0 && v!=0 && r>0)
    {
        i = v/r;
        printf("\n\nIntensidad:\t %.2f\nVoltaje:\t %.2f\nResistencia:\t %.2f\n", i, v, r);
    }
    else if (v==0 && i!=0 && r>0)
    {
        v = i*r;
        printf("\n\nIntensidad:\t %.2f\nVoltaje:\t %.2f\nResistencia:\t %.2f\n", i, v, r);
    }
    else if (r==0 && v!=0 && i!=0)
    {
        r = v/i;
        printf("\n\nIntensidad:\t %.2f\nVoltaje:\t %.2f\nResistencia:\t %.2f\n", i, v, r);
    }
    else
        printf("\nLo siento, no puedo calcularlo.");


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Ejemplos de salidas**:

calculadora ley de ohm          (Si no tienes un valor pon 0)

```
Intensidad:      0
Voltaje:         0
Resistencia:     0

Intensidad?
8
Voltaje?
230
Resistencia?
0


Intensidad:      8.00
Voltaje:         230.00
Resistencia:     28.75
```

---

```
calculadora ley de ohm          (Si no tienes un valor pon 0)

Intensidad:      0
Voltaje:         0
Resistencia:     0

Intensidad?
0
Voltaje?
230
Resistencia?
0

Lo siento, no puedo calcularlo.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente añade en el ultimo else una condición que habilite o deshabite dicha impresion.

```
    else { if(cond){printf("lo siento, no puedo calcularlo");}
```

Comment: ¿Y cual sería esa condición?

Comment: No estoy muy puesto en física, pero supongo que seria comprobar el caso de que te pasaran algún parámetro negativo o invalido para la resolución del problema.                                                                                                        else { if(i <0 || v < 0 || r <0){printf("lo siento, no puedo calcularlo");}

Answer (score 0):

La condición en la que calculas el siguiente valor, `a`, `b` y `c`, no debería estar puesta en el `if` en el que están puestas.
Me explico:

Calculas `a`, compruebas si V es cero, y calculas `b`, pero... ¿dónde lo usas? En el siguiente `if`, al que nunca accederás.

Usando los bloques `if - elseif -else`, como mencionan antes, tu código pasaría a ser algo más legible, puesto que cuando cumples una condición, no se cumplen otras (si `i` es cero, pero `v`es cero también, no lo has considerado).

Un truco muy útil para aprender a usar correctamente los bloques `if-elseif-else` es utilizar tests unitarios, desde el caso más pesimista, al más optimista. Siempre eliminarás lo peor al empezar, y evitarás problemas a la larga.

También te recomiendo encarecidamente que no incluyas, de ahora en adelante, `#include <conio.h>`, puesto que no forma parte de ninguna librería estándar. Siempre puedes usar, en vez de `getch();`, la función `getchar();`, incluida en la librería `#include <stdio.h>`.